# Updating rails value without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page that displays the date that a record was last updated:

```
<span class="updated-at">
    Last Updated: <i><%= I18n.l @record.updated_at.to_date, :format => :long  %></i>
</span>
```

The record can be updated on the page without the page having to reload the page. How can update this displayed value, without reloading the entire page?

Comment: Via JavaScript and Ajax? Via JavaScript and web sockets? ...

Comment: So you already have an Ajax call working that calls the server and updates the record? If so, just call some javascript on the server callback to change the value of this specific span, giving it an id attribute

Answer (score 0):

this code updates the updated at code every 5 seconds. change the 5000 for a different interval or select a completely different trigger.

html

```
<span class="updated-at" data-record-id="<%= @record.id %>">
  Last Updated: <i><%= I18n.l @record.updated_at.to_date, :format => :long  %></i>
</span>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){ setUpdatedAt(); }, 5000);
}

function setUpdatedAt(){
  var $target = $('.updated-at');
  var id = $target.attr('data-record-id');
  $ajax(
    url : '/records/'+id+'/updated_at',
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      $target.html(data['response']);
    }

  );

}
```

records controller

```
def updated_at
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])

  render json: {
    success: true,
    response: "Last Updated: <i>#{I18n.l @record.updated_at.to_date, :format => :long}</i>"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

with a **FORM**:
If you want to update something using a form without reloading, include remote:true in your form:

```
<%= form_for(@entity, url: update_path(@entity), remote: true) do |f| %>
```

or maybe with a **LINK**, let's say a delete. Also include remote:true in the link:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', yourclass, method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

Should also do, for any of above cases:

in your action of updating, let it respond to JS:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
end
```

Write a JS file in 'app/views/yourClass/yourUpdateActionName.js.erb' to send back to the client. You can use an id to identify the dom object, or you could traverse with jquery through the objects. Example using ID:

```
$('#updatedAt').text('new')
```

or if you are doing a delete

```
$('#updatedAt').fadeOut('new')
```